# OpenCL's clEnqueueReadBufferRect works for int but not double data type

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I need to copy some data with a certain stride from the device to the host. I already have a solution using a simple OpenCL kernel, but for certain circumstances I'd like to have the option to not use the kernel but do a strided copy using clEnqueueReadBufferRect (or its c++ variant cl::CommandQueue::enqueueReadBufferRect).

I wrote a small test problem (see below for compilable code) that copies every second entry out of an array of length 10 and stores it consecutively in an array of size 5.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#include <CL/cl.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Set up OpenCL environment

    cl::Context context;
    cl::Device device;
    cl::CommandQueue queue;

    try {

        std::vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
        cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);
        cl::Platform tauschcl_platform = all_platforms[0];

        std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
        tauschcl_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &all_devices);
        device = all_devices[0];

        std::cout << "Using OpenCL device " << device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << std::endl;

        // Create context and queue
        context = cl::Context({device});
        queue = cl::CommandQueue(context,device);

    } catch(cl::Error &error) {
        std::cout << "OpenCL exception caught: " << error.what() << " (" << error.err() << ")" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }


    /*********************/
    // Thus works with int
    // but not float nor double
    typedef int buf_t;
    /*********************/

    // Start buffer, length 10, filled with integers from 1 to 10
    buf_t *buf1 = new buf_t[10]{};
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        buf1[i] = i+1;

    // create an opencl buffer with same content
    cl::Buffer clbuf(queue, &buf1[0], &buf1[10], true);

    // receiving buffer of length 5, initialised to zero
    buf_t *buf2 = new buf_t[5]{};

    // buffer/host offsets are both (0,0,0)
    cl::size_t<3> buffer_offset;
    buffer_offset[0] = 0; buffer_offset[1] = 0; buffer_offset[2] = 0;
    cl::size_t<3> host_offset;
    host_offset[0] = 0; host_offset[1] = 0; host_offset[2] = 0;

    // We copy 5 values (with stride of 2)
    cl::size_t<3> region;
    region[0] = 1; region[1] = 5; region[2] = 1;

    try {
        queue.enqueueReadBufferRect(clbuf,
                                    CL_TRUE,
                                    buffer_offset,
                                    host_offset,
                                    region,
                                    2*sizeof(buf_t),    // buffer stride of 2
                                    0,
                                    1*sizeof(buf_t),    // host stride of 1
                                    0,
                                    buf2);
    } catch(cl::Error &error) {
        std::cout << "OpenCL exception caught: " << error.what() << " (" << error.err() << ")" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // print result
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << "#" << i << " = " << buf2[i] << " --> should be " << 2*i+1 << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

This code works perfectly when using `int` as datatype. But changing `int` in line 38 to `float` or `double` results in, well, nothing it seems, the receiving host array `buf2` still contains all zero. From what I can find there is no limitation on clEnqueueReadBufferRect regarding which data type it can work with.

I tested the above code on Intel and NVIDIA and on both it behaves the same way. I'm quite stumped and don't know what else to try to solve this. Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This left me puzzled for a while, but I think I have a solution:

According to this [1.2 official reference](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueReadBufferRect.html)* :

> region
>
> - The (width, height, depth) in bytes of the 2D or 3D rectangle being read or written. For a 2D rectangle copy, the depth value given by region[2] should be 1.

But that is misleading at best and doesn't work at all. The correct format of this parameter as written in the [1.2 official specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf) [page 77] is:

> *region* defines the (width in bytes, height in rows, depth in slices)
> of the 2D or 3D rectangle being read or written. For a 2D rectangle
> copy, the depth value given by region[2] should be 1. The values in
> region cannot be 0.

And indeed  `region[0] = 1*sizeof(buf_t); region[1] = 5; region[2] = 1;` makes the code run correctly on my Intel 630HD and NVIDIA 1050TI GPUs.

*[2.0 official reference](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueReadBufferRect.html) shows the correct format. 2.1 too, but I think 1.2 is heavily used and perhaps should be corrected.

Comment: Yes, that's it, thanks a million, now it works as expected! I agree that the 1.2 reference (the C++ Wrapper API uses the same language) should be updated.